# Prevent the duplciate path/route usage in the routerLink

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-router

Thats my html file:

```
  <a [routerLink]="['tests/...']">Tests</a>
```

This terminal route is already defined the parent component Routes configuration.

Due to maintaining my software I would like to declare kind of a constant string and re-use it from my Routes and routerLink.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly access constants from the template of a component.

You can inject a service that provides access to your "global" values like

```
@Injectable() 
export class RoutePaths {
  test:string = 'tests/...';
  other:string = 'other';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'some-comp',
  template: `
<a [routerLink]="[routePaths.test]">Tests</a>
<a [routerLink]="[routePaths.other]">Tests</a>
`})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private routePaths:RoutePaths) {}
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [RoutePaths]);
```